# Rails Internationalization Switching Language No Route Matches on Fail Validation Form Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I have a Rails site with i18 in which a user can switch language on the menu bar, 'en' and 'km' in my case.

What I understand from switching language approach is to merge current param with the locale. 'Get' method is happened, I suppose.

I have a resource, 'products' for example.
The products resource HAS NO 'show' page.

```
resources :products, except: [:show]
```

When update a product with some invalid data. Let say I have a validation the presence of name of the product, but I leave the product name blank in my form. Then the form is rendered back the 'edit' form but the 'update' action, but notice the 'url' is '/products/id' which is exactly like 'show' action.

In this step, I switch the language. As expected, the locale is merged with current param. So, the 'get' method is happened now with the url 'products/id?_method=patch...'

No route matches raises since I have no 'show' action.

Can anybody suggest me a good way to handle this please?
I can escape this problem by redirecting the 'get' method of 'show' action to somewhere possible like its index page. Anyway, I wonder if there are more better ways.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`resources` create a mapping like:

- `GET /products` - `ProductsController#index`
- `GET /products/:id` - `ProductsController#show` (not present in your case)
- `GET /products/:id/edit` - `ProductsController#edit`
- `PUT /products/:id` - `ProductsController#update`
- `POST /products` - `ProductsController#create`
- `DELETE /products/:id` - `ProductsController#destroy`

The reason you see `/products/:id` in the URL is because this is the default route for the `update` action. What you can do is to change

```
resources :products, except: [:show]
```

to

```
resources :products, except: [:edit]
```

and show the edition form in `ProductsController#show`. If there's no distinction between viewing and editing the product then you don't have to indicate edition in the route with the `/edit` suffix.

Comment: As I understand, the way you mentioned is to preserve a place, show page in this case, once the update info is invalid. It's my fault that I forgot to mention about creating a new object. It happens like the updating one. So, I'm afraid we cannot preserve a place for this case since the url after invalid new object creation is '/products' which is exactly 'index' page.

Answer (score 0):

How many users will switch languages only after validations failed? Not that many, i think.

So a simple solution would be to:

- change locale and show the same page if method was GET
- change locale and redirect to *home* if method was NOT GET

Comment: Of course, not many, but some. To me, it's a little bit annoying to bring me to another page I do not expect to be. That's why I want to hear much idea. I'll consider your idea. Anyway, just let me hear from some other.